# PUT request in AWS Lambda returns error code 400

Tags: java, aws-lambda, http-error

I am writing a lambda function handler to perform a PUT request. It returns me a 400 error. When I used the same code as a stand alone Java application, it works perfect.

Summary of what is happening:
I am retrieving a file from an s3 bucket to lambda function and making a PUT request. On receiving the output I am storing it into a different s3 bucket. As said earlier, this whole process works perfect when I run it as a Java application. But when I run the same logic as a lambda function, it returns an error code 400..

Comment: Can you post the error message? Which API call throws error code 400? Normally AWS gives you exact error message apart from error code. It sounds like some problem with IAM permissions attached to the lambda function.

Comment: The event data in CloudWatch is as follows:
START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST 
 ROW_ID,petal_length,petal_width,sepal_length,sepal_width,class,Probability_setosa,Probability_versicolor,Probability_virginica 
 1,1.4,0.2,5.1,3.5,Iris-setosa,1,0,0 
 Got stuff from s3. 
Crossed certification part. 
Error:  
Response msg is: Bad Request, Response code: 400 
Process completed. 
END RequestId: xxx

>ROW_ID,petal_length,.....
This data is stored in a file in an S3 bucket which is being sent as a PUT request to a server by invoking a lambda func. Output is received in a different S3 bucket.

Comment: The lines in between like "Got stuff from S3." , "Crossed certification part." and "Process completed" are all Console outputs I have deliberately written to keep a track.

Comment: The lambda function is trying to access an EC2 instance where the request is being made. I am using the Public IP address of the EC2 instance in order to make the request. In the security group of the instance, I have kept it as 0.0.0.0 for HTTPS. So my application should have access to it.